# dc.js pieChart not updating after filterAll()

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I recently found my pie chart using dc.js is not updating properly. The dimension.filterAll() works fine and the dc.renderAll() will refresh the page and redraw the chart, but the chart is not reflecting the data being filtered.
Here is the code.

```
<script>
var data = [{date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
            {date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}]; 

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.total = d.http_404 + d.http_200 + d.http_302;
        d.Year = d.date.getFullYear();
    });
    var yearDim;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cx = crossfilter(data);

        yearDim = cx.dimension(function (d) { return d.Year; });            
        var yearGroup = yearDim.group().reduce(
                    function (p, v) {
                        ++p.count;
                        return p;
                    },
                    function (p, v) {
                        --p.count;
                        return p;
                    },
                    function () {
                        return {
                            count: 0
                        };
                    }
                    );

        mypie = dc.pieChart('#pie-chart');
        mypie
            .dimension(yearDim)
            .group(yearGroup)
            .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                return d.value.count;
            });

        dc.renderAll();
    });

    function resetYear() {
        yearDim.filterAll();
        dc.redrawAll();
        dc.renderAll();

    }
</script>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div>            
        <button type="button" onclick="resetYear();">Year</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the chart when the filter changes - that's why it's better always to manipulate the dimension through the chart (with `mypie.filter(null)` instead of `yearDim.filterAll()`).

Reason: Currently there are no getters in crossfilter, so dc.js needs to maintain a mirror of the current filter state.

(Additionally, you shouldn't need to `dc.renderAll()` when changing filters - that will cause extra movement. `dc.redrawAll()` should be enough, and `mypie.redrawGroup()` is more specific.)